# How to create 'droppable' box with super-hands and physics component in a-frame

Tags: aframe

I am trying to recreate a stripped back version of the `superhands`/`physics` a-frame demo [here](https://wmurphyrd.github.io/aframe-super-hands-component/examples/physics/)

All the grabbing/dragging/physics works well but I cannot get the `droppable` box to fire the event on collision with the `draggable` one.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f45qhosq/) with my code (with all the scripts its quite long) but please let me know if you would like me to copy the code here.

I'm sure I am missing something simple here but I can't see it, I feel like I have everything that the original example has but I can't get that event to fire, not even to log something to the console.

This is my first venture into physics and controllers so apologies if I'm making some rookie errors. I should mention that I am testing initially on desktop using mouse to drag, hoping that getting the basics working here will scale up to the headsets.

Advice much appreciated as ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current config, you have only the grabbable box, but not the droppable target, visible for collision detection:

```
 progressive-controls="objects: .tape"
```

Change this to a selector that includes all interactive objects in your scene:

```
 progressive-controls="objects: .tape, #tape_player"
```

Internally, `progressive-controls` sets up collision detection using either the A-Frame `raycaster`, for desktop & mobile modes, or the A-Frame Extras `sphere-collider`, for roomscale mode, (or another component of your choosing if you customize the config). It passes on the selector you define in the `objects` property to those components to control which entities will be watched for collisions/intersections, and only those entities will be interactive through `super-hands`.

It is good practice to choose a discriminating selector that only targets entities you want to be interactive because collision detection has a significant performance cost, so you don't want to waste time checking unnecessary collisions.

Comment: Thank you W. Murphy - I didn't spot that in your? example. I appreciate the explanation as well. Super-hands is amazing by the way, so great to have an experience accessible on all platforms with just one component.